# can not cast view group to edit text in android

Tags: android, gridview, casting, viewgroup

i want to save data in edittext in gridview.When user click capture button .It will save data with Sharedpreference in method onPause().But i can't cast viewGroup to edittext.

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Button btPhoto, btSave;
private GridView gridview;
private File imgFile;
private String path;
private ArrayList<File> List_File;
private static final int imageCode = 100;
private Context context;
SharedPreferences preference;
SharedPreferences.Editor edit;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btPhoto);
    btSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_save);
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    preference = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


    path = "/TongFolder/";
    context = this;
    List_File = new ArrayList<File>();
    File imgDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+path);
    imgDir.mkdirs();
    boolean check = imgDir.isDirectory();
    if(check == true){
    btPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            capture();

        }
    });
    }else{
        System.out.println("not create");
    }
 }


public void capture(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imgFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+path, 
            "img_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imgFile));
    startActivityForResult(intent, imageCode);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if(requestCode == imageCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        //add path to arrayList
        List_File.add(imgFile);
        for (File file : List_File) {
            String showPath = file.getPath();
            System.out.println(showPath);
        }

        gridview.setAdapter(new gridViewAdapter(context, List_File));

    }

}

public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    // save data to preference

    int size = gridview.getChildCount();
    System.out.println("size of gridview "+size);

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            ViewGroup child_grid = (ViewGroup) gridview.getChildAt(i);

                //intialize

                EditText edit_num = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
                EditText edit_info = new EditText(getApplicationContext());

                //get editText in child_gridview
                edit_num = (EditText) child_grid.getChildAt(1);
                edit_info = (EditText) child_grid.getChildAt(2);

                String num = edit_num.getText().toString();
                String info = edit_info.getText().toString();

                System.out.println("data in position "+i+" is "+num+"and"+info);

        }   


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And this is my logcat error

```
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.imagecapture/com.example.imagecapture.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2858)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:140)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1248)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at com.example.imagecapture.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:125)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5304)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1240)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2889)
02-19 15:05:54.201: E/AndroidRuntime(30390):    ... 12 more
```

this is my main layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btPhoto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="photo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_save"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="save" />
```

And this is my gridview_item layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_num"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="No." >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:hint="Explain about this picture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post the layout file for the each cell in `GridView` ...

Comment: simply try as `View childview = gridview.getChildAt(i);` without casting to ViewGroup

Comment: You are trying to cast a `LinearLayout` into `Edittext`, that is why exception was raised.

Comment: Post the related XML file

Comment: How can i cast view_group to edittext.Because i want to get value in edittext to save data with sharedPreference

Answer (score 0):

Your EditTexts has ids. You can find Views by them.

```
//get editText in child_gridview
edit_num = (EditText) child_grid.findViewById(R.id.editText_num);
edit_info = (EditText) child_grid.findViewById(R.id.editText_info);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `findViewById()`.

edit_num = (EditText) child_grid.findViewById(R.id.editText_num);

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)